# sudo npm install -g ios-deploy error

Tags: cordova, npm, iosdeployment

So I was trying to learn Cordova/PhoneGap and I'm currently learning "Build". Based on the tutorial that I'm following, I need to sudo npm install -g ios-sim. It was successful then after that, the tutorial told me to install ios-deploy. And I did sudo npm install -g ios-deploy and there's an error came up:

```
Desktop/Cordova/myApp$ sudo npm install -g ios-deploy
npm WARN lifecycle ios-deploy@1.9.0~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) ios-deploy@1.9.0 ./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ios-deploy-298c9491
npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ios-deploy"
npm ERR! node v6.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/jasoncuray/Desktop/Cordova/myApp/npm-debug.log
```

Can anyone please help me with this? I'm newbie trying to just learn from tutorials. Thanks! I'm using Macbook Pro 2015, all installation was done prior to the tutorial that I'm following.

Answer (score 5):

Problem Solved with this:

```
npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true
```